# Validate specific field in DRF serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I have a model with a `JSONField`.

`model.py`

```
class Categories(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     details = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Currently I'm using `serializers.ModelSerializer` for serializing this above model:

`serializers.py`

```
class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Categories
         fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'details')
```

Due to this, the details field is only checked to contain `valid json`. What i really need to do is to perform some custom validation based on the **Json Schema** defined for details field. However since I don't want any other custom validations for rest of the fields, I would like to keep using the validations provided by `serializers.ModelSerializer`. Is there any way I can override a validation for just one field, probably by writing a custom serializer *for just the details field*?

> Note question is not about how to write a custom Validator, but about how to use that custom validator on a field in the serializer inheriting `ModelSerializer`

Answer (score 10):

DRF's serializers provide [field level](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) validation option. You can perform details field validation by implementing `validate_details` method:

```
class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Categories
         fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'details')

     def validate_details(self, value):
        if value['not_valid']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not valid")
        return value
```

Comment: can I use my custom validator class instead of the function? Or maybe inside the `validate_details` function? I need to use a class because there are various schema's for `details` field, so i'd like to benefit from validator inheritance over here.

Comment: @IshanKhare you can try to pass class based validator http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#class-based with field's validators argument http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#validators

Comment: something like `validators=[MyDetailsValidator('details')]` ?

Comment: @IshanKhare no, like this: `details = serializers.JSONField(validators=[MyDetailsValidator]`

Comment: What kind of ViewSet was used in this case?

Comment: @Rafi it doesn't matter. Field level validation will work with when serializer's `is_valid` method called.

Comment: I am using `CreateAPIView` and `perform_create` but it is not hitting the breakpoint in the `validate_field_name` function of the serializer. Do I need to overwrite the `create` function before I call `perform_create`?

Comment: @Rafi as far as I know `CreateAPIView` calls `is_valid` serializer's method by default. So it should work.

Comment: Why isn't this type of validation doesn't work with HiddenField ?

Answer (score 1):

The other way around is to validate `JSONFiled` on Django models level, you can use [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) package.

For example

```
SCHEMA = { put JSON Schema draft here }
```

Let's validate

```
from jsonschema import validate, ValidationError

def validate_json_filed(value):
    try:
        validate(value, SCHEMA)
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(e)
```

Then just

```
name = JSONField(validators=[validate_json_field], default=dict, blank=True)
```

You can validate rest of the field using DRF validators.